# added products not displaying user interface using Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, catalog

I have added a product with some new attribute set, In admin side, catalog listing page shows the products and when I open configured product, association tab shows the associated product.

I cleared cache and indexed properly before checking.

Refer Below scrrenshots:

1. Admin catalog listing:
   [image]

2.When opening configurable product Showing association:
[image]

3. User side:
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check

1. go to catalog=>>manage product and open product which you want to display
2. check in general tab =>>status Enable.
3. Inventory tab =>>Qty =>> don't left empty && stock availability=>> in stock.
4. categories tab=>> select category in which you want to display.

Comment: Yes you are right. stock availability selected as `Out Of Stock` by default, can we change this as in stock by default? More over, when I enter Quantity field as 10, it is no point the stock availability as `Out Of Stock`

Comment: check it  http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/system-configuration-inventory-settings   or  http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-configure-and-manage-inventory-settings.html#gref